# How to delete a file in a LUN that gives an error?

Tags: windows-server-2003, lun, chkdsk

I have a 1.5GB LUN, on a QNAP NAS.

The LUN is attached to a W2K3, and has some folders shared on it.

On one sub-folder there is a specific file, that is corrupted. I need to delete it, but I can't even access it.
The file is
[image]

The error I get when trying to delete is (current user is the Domain Administrator)
[image]

When I want to schedule a CHKDSK, it says it can't, as it needs to be done in reboot. but in Reboot, the LUNS are not yet attached.
[image]

- What else can I try please?

UPDATE: Issue solved.
I ran CHKDSK from the command line (actually forgot it even exists). It done massive deletes and updated security ID's on 100k's of file.
The trouble file has been deleted, and I assume ton's of others as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't mention how this LUN is shared? FC, FCoE, iSCSI?

Comment: This is now solved - I ran CHKDSK from the command line: CHKDSK /F

Comment: This site is for PROFESSIONAL sysadmins, are you sure this is the right place for you?

Comment: How would I become a professional if I will not ask? Learn? Try? At least I know how to ask the questions. Haven't you ever missed a command?  Have a great sysday

Answer (score 0):

I ran CHKDSK from the command line: CHKDSK /F

*using windows to much, makes you forget command line functions.